# How to turn off Entity Framework CF Migrations for an environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to turn off Entity Framework using the `web.config`? In the application I'm developing we have the following environments

- Development
- Continuous Integration
- Integration Testing
- Production

The Integration Testing and Production databases are managed by a database administrator, so we have to send them a script to make changes to the database.

I've spent hours Googling and looking through old projects, and I can't find how to do this or remember if we ever turned off migrations on the old projects in the first place.

From the lack of information I'm doubting if what I'm asking is needed or possible, but there is something in the back of my head that's annoying me about this so I thought I'd ask the experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to simply delete the `dbo._MigrationHistory` table from these environments. If that table doesn't exist, then only an "initial" migration can ever be generated against that database, which will fail if someone tries to actually apply it to a database with existing tables.

Comment: Actually, we use the scripting technique you mention on your blog. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Answer (score 2):

You could set the database initializer in the config file  as described at the bottom [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx), so you can have an updating initializer in the environments you want

Comment: I was looking at that page already. Is the Iniatializer not only used when the database doesn't exist ? IE it tells EntityFramework what to create a new database etc

Comment: Depends on the initializer. There's `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`, for example, which will, as its name implies, completely recreate the database any time the schema changes. Typically for working with an existing database, you simply specify the initializer as `null`, which effectively turns off initialization entirely.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that setting the initializer is done in code, so its kind of all or nothing unless you do something hacky like use compiler directives or some sort of switch statement based on Web.config settings.

Comment: @Chris The blog shows exactly how to set the initializer from config without any home made hacks.